# How to pass parameter from view to template in django?

Tags: django

I want to pass value of variable from django view to template.

view:

```
def countsnippet(request):
 checkins = Attendee.objects.filter(checkin=True).count()
 return render( request, 'search/countsnippet.html', {'inft': checkins} )
```

Template snippet:

```
<div class="row" >
  {% block content %}
  <p>INFT : {% 'inft' %}</p>
  {% endblock %}
</div>
```

I want to pass checkins value to template, but using above approach is giving me error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *render* a "variable" by placing it between double curly brackets (`{{ }}`), like:

```
<div class="row" >
  {% block content %}
  <p>INFT : {{ inft }}</p>
  {% endblock %}
</div>
```

The variable name is *not* surrounded by quotes, and you can treat it thus like an identifier.

You can furthermore use a sequence of identifiers separated by dots (like `{{ foo.bar }}`) to access the `bar` attribute/element of `foo`.

Furthermore Django templates allow extra features like *template filters*, etc. See the [Django documentation on the template language](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/language/) for an in-depth article.

Comment: Thanks !!
Any suggestion about how can I pass multiple variables like that and access in template?

Comment: @JayVasant: well the dictionary you pass can contain multiple key-value pairs, like: `return render( request, 'search/countsnippet.html', {'inft': checkins, 'foo': 'bar'} )`